# How to get popup notification action buttons back if it dismissed?

Tags: gnome, notification

It looks like that GNOME popup notification will dismissed if mouse move over it. There is no chance to do with the button again.

[popup notification with buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQEJM.png)

[dismissed notification has no buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CwkzR.png)